# Erro ao inserir dados no banco SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Classe que cria o banco

```
public class CriaBanco extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String NOME_BANCO = "lista.db";
private static final int VERSAO_BANCO = 1;

public CriaBanco(Context context) {
    super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO_BANCO);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    final String SQL_CRIAR_TABELA = "CREATE TABLE lista_notify (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT "+
            "hora_notificacao TEXT NOT NULL"+
            "texto_notificacao TEXT NOT NULL)";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CRIAR_TABELA);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

MainActivity.java onde se cria a instancia da classe CriaBanco.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText ed_hora_notificacao;
private EditText ed_texto_notificacao;
private CriaBanco mDbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CriaBanco banco = new CriaBanco(this);

}}
```

Método que insere dados no banco

```
public void cadastrar_periodic(View v){
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("hora_notificacao", "Toto");
    values.put("texto_notificacao", "Terrier");

    long newRowId = db.insert("lista_notify", null, values);
}
```

Texto do erro que dá

```
Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

Comment: Já tentou depois que inserir chamar o db.close();

Comment: já sim, mas continua o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Traduzindo o erro:

> Por favor, corrija sua aplicação para finalizar as transações em andamento
>   e feche o banco de dados quando ele não for mais necessário.

Olha só, você está chamando o `mDbHelper` no método `cadastrar_periodic` sem instancia-lo. Veja abaixo como deve ficar seu método:

```
public void cadastrar_periodic(View v){
    mDbHelper = new CriaBanco(this); // criando uma instancia 

    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("hora_notificacao", "Toto");
    values.put("texto_notificacao", "Terrier");

    long newRowId = db.insert("lista_notify", null, values);

    db.close(); // fechando o banco de dados
}
```

Comment: @demetrius veja se resolve seu problema assim?!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a conexão ainda não esteja criada tente atribuir o new CriBanco para mHelper como abaixo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText ed_hora_notificacao;
private EditText ed_texto_notificacao;
private CriaBanco mDbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     this.mDbHelper = new CriaBanco(this);

}}
```

> outra coisa tente fechar a conexão com o banco ao final da linha que inseri usando o comando `db.close();`